# What's the difference in Vue @click between calling a method directly and calling in inside a function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm learning nuxt and the tutor has a function to add an item called `updateTodo` and attached it to a button as the follwoing

`script`

```js
<script setup>  
  const updateTodo = async (id) => {
    if (!input) return;

    await $fetch(`/api/todo/${id}`, { method: 'PUT' });
  };
</script>
```

`template`

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new todo..." v-model="input" />
    <NButton @click="() => updateTodo(todo.id)">Add</NButton>
  </div>
</template>
```

I dont know why he didn't call it directly (eg. `@click="updateTodo(todo.id)`). I tried to do it and it worked. Is there a reason i dont know or it's just a preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are allowed.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events

> The usage would be `v-on:click="handler"` or with the shortcut, `@click="handler"`. The handler value can be one of the following:
>
> 1. Inline handlers: Inline JavaScript to be executed when the event is triggered (similar to the native onclick attribute).
> 2. Method handlers: A property name or path that points to a method defined on the component.

However, note that this isn't necessarily always the case. In some libraries/frameworks, something like `onclick="yourFunction()"` might call the method immediately, and use the returned value as an event listener. This is usually not what you want, unless you're returning a function.

Comment: good to know but i didnt grasp the last part. How can i call a function and what the function returns will be used as an event listener. I'm already activating a function at a certain event listener i'm confused

Answer (score 1):

1. in this case you call directly, you don't require event parmas here.

> ```
> <NButton @click="updateTodo(todo.id)">Add</NButton>
> ```

2. but in a certain case, you need event parament to get the value of the input (e.target.value) or want to prevent the default of that event(e.preventDefault) i.e

**a.** you call **anyFunction** in each time, then

> ```
> <input @input="anyFunction">
> ```

**b.** but you want to pass function if enter value is greater than 100 or anything else then you need to pass as function so you get event as params like

> ```
> <input   @input="(e) => e.target.value > 100 && anyFunction">
> ```

**In other words, if there is no argument in the function for the particular event then you don't need to pass the function. else you need to pass the function.**